# Facebook page can't open in webview

Tags: java, android, facebook, webview, android-webview

If I try to load a facebook profile in a webview, I'm getting an error if I use a `WebViewClient` to display it inside the internal webview and not on an external browser:

```
webView=new WebView(ctx);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/Google");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

It gives this error:

[image]

It is like it is trying to redirect to an internal protocol called `fb://profile/` that it is not working in the internal webview, and because of that, is giving `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Any help with this? Some time ago this worked perfectly